# Make WiFi Router Using Arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, ethernet-shield

```
void switch_led() {
bool SwitchReading = digitalRead(SWITCH);
if (SwitchReading == HIGH) {
Serial.println("Now pressed....");
state = state + 1;
if (state % 2 != 0) {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  char data1[] = "{""LDRValue"": 88888888}";
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to led server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 8040)) {
    Serial.println("connected to post server");
    client.println("POST /api/sensor HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.2.116:8040");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(sizeof(data1));
    client.println();
    client.print(data1);
    Serial.println("1.finish");
  }
  Serial.println("2.finish");
}
else {
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  char data2[] = "{""LDRValue"": 1111111111}";
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to led server...");
  if (client.connect(server, 8040)) {
    Serial.println("connected to post server");
    client.println("POST /api/sensor HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.2.116:8040");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(sizeof(data2));
    client.println();
    client.print(data2);
    Serial.println("3.finish");
  }
  Serial.println("4.finish");
}
delay(500);
   }
}
```

It works perfect for the first and second posts in both Arduino and API but at the third post it works fine on Arduino but it takes long time on the API(about 2 minutes to get the post). The fourth and the fifth posts also works fine but the sixth is same as the third. Knowing

Comment: no "Connection: close" and client.stop()?

Comment: PS Host shouldn't contain the port number. That is; `client.println("Host: 192.168.2.116:8040");` should be `client.println("Host: 192.168.2.116");`